# Will we ever be able to find the universal cause?

Tags: metaphysics, cosmology

The universe can be thought of as a (curved) spacetime with matter and energy inside it and with an internal energy. The last is not matter based and represents dark energy which can be seen as a negative curvature of spacetime. In the light of a further developed theory of spacetime the universe can even exist for an eternity. It always existed and will exist forever.

How are views that posit different universal origins (the origins of the universe) to be interpreted? If there is no first material cause needed for the universe to exist how is another cause to be interpreted? As a cause that made the eternity in time to come into existence at once? Or in twice maybe? For sure it is no material cause. If it was it would be part of the material universe.

Comment: Temporal causality is currently in question; it has been proven experimentally that at least one of temporal causality, locality and quantum realism is false, but we have no idea which. What then do you regard as a valid understanding of causality and the necessary characteristic for a Universal Cause?

Comment: @GuyInchbald Good question. Let me pause for reflection.

Comment: @GuyInchbald locality is mentioned. I think this is the one that is not there in Nature. In quantum field theory particles travel on all possible paths at the same time. Even backwards in space (anti particles). This is pretty nonlocal. When a state is collapsed to, this will  cause all paths to be reduced to the state at hand. Pretty non local too. Temporal causation must somehow exist. Maybe the creation of a pair doesnt ivolve prior time but somehow this creation must be preceded in time. Ny some as yet unperceived process (hidden variables which can only be nonlocal).

Comment: The technical problem is that if you abandon temporal causality and/or quantum realism, then you can keep locality and still explain quantum entanglement. I am attracted to the view that none is fundamental but all are emergent properties or aspects of the systems we study. It is hard to imagine anything less confined in time and space than a Feynman path integral, nor anything less ontologically substantial than the wave function of a buckyball.